# How to retrieve a node from a Page in CQ5?

Tags: xpath, aem, sling

I have 2 Questions:

1) By using the Page name i did Xpath Query like this:

```
//element(*, cq:Page)
[
fn:name() = 'hello-world ' 
]
```

and i am able to find the page too (tried in crxde Lite and its finding the correct page). how to Convert the QueryResult to Page type?

2)After converting the result to Page type, how to retrieve a particular node under jcr:content of this Page?

I am new to CQ5, so i dont have good knowledge on existing API's provided for this. any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryResult` wraps a collection of `Node`s. Both these classes are part of the JCR API. On the other hand, `Page` is a part of the CQ API. There is no direct way to transform a `Node` into a `Page` even if both objects represent the same physical thing. The only thing you can do is to take the `Node` path and retrieve a `Page` using this path:

```
PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
QueryResult result = ...;

NodeIterator nodes = result.getNodes();
while (nodes.hasNext()) {
    Node node = nodes.nextNode();
    Page page = pageManager.getPage(node.getPath());
    // do anything you want with the Page
}
```

About the second question - you may use [`Page#getContentResource(String)`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getContentResource%28java.lang.String%29) method to take any `Resource` from the page `jcr:content`, like:

```
Resource resource = page.getContentResource("parsys/text");
```

`Resource` is a part of the Sling API. You may cast it to `Node` using `adaptTo()` method:

```
Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
```

However it's a good idea to learn how to use the Sling API. For starters, you may read resource/node properties by adapting the resource to the `ValueMap` class:

```
ValueMap map = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
map.get("myProperty", ""); // the second argument is the default value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomek!!! It really helped in understanding the Basic stuff.. this should work :)

Answer (score -2):

If you are asking about JSP code, include file `global.jsp` and access it via properties (implicit object):

```
String title = properties.get("title", ""); // title = node name
```

Comment: Thanks for replying parveen :)